# Performance advantages of an array of function pointer over if blocks

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a Solver class that reads data from a System class and calculates a solution for the system current state. Depending on the system data, there are different member functions that I should call to get each value of a huge matrix. My question is: If I use function pointers instead of if statements, will I get better performance? (this procedure is repeated several times and I wish to optimize it)

System

```
class System
{
  friend class Solver;

  public:
    void print();
    //...
  private:
    double x[n];
    int equationType[n];
    //...
}
```

Solver with If statements

```
class Solver
{
  public:
    //...
    void solve(){
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
            if(sys->equationType[i] == 1)
                solveForEq1(i, x[i]);
            else if(sys->equationType[i] == 2)
                solveForEq2(i, x[i]);
            else if //...
    }
  private:
    System *sys;
    void solveForEq1(int, double);
    void solveForEq2(int, double);
    //...
}
```

Solver with function pointers (will this actually work? and faster?)

```
typedef void (Solver::*MemFuncPtr)(int, double);

class Solver
{
  public:
    //...
    Solver(System* s) : sys(s){
        mfp[0] = &Solver::solveForEq1;
        mfp[1] = &Solver::solveForEq2;
    }
    void solve(){
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            *(mfp[equationType[i]])(i, x[i]);
    }
  private:
    System *sys;
    MemFuncPtr mfp[2];
    void solveForEq1(int, double);
    void solveForEq2(int, double);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you measure how long it took? There's your answer! *PS, sorry if I seem harsh, we all do it*

Comment: Please don't be sorry about seeming harsh. I was just expecting something like "Of course, if statements will mess up pipelining and function pointers will not". Since I can't test the program's performance on every computer, I thought some knowledge could help.

Comment: Well, without testing it myself, I would have thought that it depends on the number of `if else` statements. Why? Say you have `100,000,000` different possibilities, and the one passed in was the last `if else` to be checked, you'd have to go through ALL those statements. If you used an index in a container (such as your array), you just give it the index and dereference it.

Comment: I didn't read the whole thing, but did you consider `switch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work faster without the if statement.

If statements make your CPU chace 80% of the positive branch, which leads to cache misses when going for negative branches.

Whenever you are able to get rid of a "if" statement then you made a huge improvement.

Considering your case where you don't have the positive branch the usual case scenario (usual case scenario for a positive branch is something like if (argument!=NULL) ), then you should have a significant performance gain.

The performance gain also varies accourding to CPU type (RISC or CISC).

Comment: Some pretty confused code coming from the OP, however I approve of the general advice to favour virtual functions. Other than that, this answer has too many assumptions and not enough quantifiable data to be taken as given. Eg. where did the 80% come from? How many cycles does a cache miss cost? Is removing an if statement always better? (exercise for reader: under what circumstances is this statement not true?) How does CISC or RISC impact performance of if statements in general?

Comment: You are right fixxxer, but in order to answer all these questions one must research how branch prediction is handled on both CISC and RISC. From what some people say that CISC precaches the instruction set of the most-likely to be taken route according to it's chanche to be taken, while RISC does both branches and only take the result from the positive one. OFC this information might be obosolete, and each manufacturer uses his own way to deal with it. A cache miss results in 250% penalty of performance on an arm processor. Safer to say that a good practice is to avoid if statments if possible